# What is the proper way to terminate the Vue CLI 3 development server?

Tags: macos, vue-cli-3

I have just started to use Vue CLI 3 for a project and it looks like I am not terminating a development session correctly. Like [the docs suggests](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html) I start a development session with:

```
npm run serve
```

Which gives me the port to work on:

> App running at:
>    - Local:   http://localhost:8087/
>    - Network: http://192.168.0.100:8087/

When I'm done working on my project I hit `Ctrl-Z` and I have my command line back. Yay!

But this leaves something still listening on the port:

```
lsof -i TCP:8087
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    58122 jannie   14u  IPv4 0xc7ce0b7d644a357d      0t0  TCP *:8087 (LISTEN)
```

How can I terminate the development server gracefully so that it frees the port when I am done?

Comment: Try using `Ctrl-C` instead. It allows the application to gracefully shut down.

Comment: Okay! Learning new things every day. @ikkentim can you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. BTW, how did you know this?

Comment: I always used `Ctrl-C`. A while ago `Ctrl-Z` was actually a TIL for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `Ctrl-C` instead. It allows the application to gracefully shut down.